# Can I double my throughput when I double my cores?

Tags: python, gunicorn

I currently have an server with an E5-2620V3 6 cores cpu.

I run an python app using nginx and gunicorn.

If I load test the app with 150 clients in a continuous loop it has a throughput of 20k req/minute. However the cpu is only used for 40%.

I can switch to the same cpu with 12 cores.

Will this double my throughput given that there are no I/O, memory bottlenecks?

Comment: If the CPU isn't maxed out, the bottleneck is elsewhere.

Comment: Can you give us a "top" screen during the benchmark?

Answer (score 0):

You must find out what device is the bottleneck.

So far we know that it isn't the CPU, which means that increasing the core count should do very little or have a slight negative effect because most higher core cpus use lower clock rates.

I like to use iotop to monitor disk usage, iftop to monitor network load, and htop to monitor cpu and ram usage. If you put them all in tmux you can watch them all at once. Look for the thing with the most load. Depending on what is causing